# Is my inductor really 22µH?

Tags: inductor

I have a package of 10 inductors, all of which are supposed to be 22µH, but they all have "220" printed on the case. It does not seem right when I compare to an otherwise identical (same type) inductor with an inductance of 3.3µH, which has "3R3" printed on it. Is it just odd ordering or am I missing something? Inductor is an SDR0604 type.

Comment: I don't get it, what else would you expect the marking "220" to mean?  In most electronics contexts it means 22.

Comment: @Nick T, given that the other one was "3R3" I'd expect "220" to mean "220R" or 220µH.

Comment: Maybe it's 22 Henries.  Were the inductors delivered with a forklift?

Comment: With +/-5% components, all you need are 2 digits plus one for order-of-magnitude.  Just like on resistors and capacitors, there are 2 mantissa digits and one for radix.

Comment: MEasure them. It's the only way to know.

Comment: @Fake Name, LCR meter is on my list but my poor student budget can't afford it - just spend £80 on a new multimeter.

Comment: @Thomas O - Do you have oscilloscope, a signal generator, and a resistor?

Comment: @Fake Name, have scope and resistor, no signal generator yet either... that's on the list too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be read as 22 × 10<sup>0</sup> µH and 3.3 µH respectively.  The R is a decimal, the last digit otherwise is an exponent.

Answer (score 15):

There are two ways of marking parts...

A Three digit code for values from 10 and up

```
X Y Z
X - First digit
Y - Second digit
Z - Power of ten

220 would be 22 = 22 x 10^0 (1)
221 would be 220 = 22 x 10^1 (10)
222 would be 2,200 = 22 x 10^2 (100)
223 would be 22,000 = 22 x 10^3 (1000)
```

The Minimum for this coding would be 
100 = 10 x 10^0
and the Maximum would be
999 = 99,000,000,000 = 99 x 10^9 (1,000,000,000)

For values under 10

you use a character to replace the decimal point

e.g. 
3R3 = 3.3
R33 = 0.33

R is used for Ohms.

For resistors the value is usually in Ohms
For Capacitors the value is usually in pico farads

e.g. a Capacitor marked 103 would be 103 pF = 10 x 10^3 (1000) pF = 10nF = 0.01uF

For Inductors the value is usually in micro henrys
e.g. a Inductor marked 220 woulf be 22uH = 22 x 10^0 (1) uH

The part marked 3R3 is a 3.3 ohm resistor as R is used on resistors.

Comment: I think "R" can be used on inductors too, but I have no idea why they use that convention. Maybe "L" wouldn't be clear enough; suppose it could be read as a 7 upside down...

Comment: Why couldn't they just write 22 µH as "22"?

Comment: @Wonko The Sane: You say the minimum for this coding is 100 (meaning 10 x 10^0 = 10)... but why can't you have 010 (meaning 01 x 10^0 = 1)?

Comment: @BG100: If you did that then you lose significant digits as you're putting useless leading zeros in your mantissa (significand).  How would you express 1.5, or 3.3 as in the OP question?

Comment: @endolith: Because part values are really logarithmic, it's better to use a consistent method that is exponential in some respect.  Using only three digits, we can cover 10 to 99 billion--10 orders of magnitude--with 5% precision.  To be somewhat consistent with that useful method, a decimal character is massaged in to go down to 0.10, 2 orders lower.  For 1% resistors, this doesn't work, so I think I've seen some with 4 characters, but others (smaller ones that can't fit 4 chars) use a code, usually [EIA-96](http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/eia96-smd-resistors.php).

Comment: @Nick: Are 22 µH and 220 µH both common values in this logarithmic system?  Yes.  Does a plain "220" confuse everyone who sees it for the first time?  Yes.  So why not write it in a different way that represents the same value without confusion, like "22_" or "22R" instead of "220"?

Comment: @endolith "I suffered for my knowledge, now it's your turn"

Answer (score 4):

220 means that the value is 22 times 10^0, or 22uH. It's a similar notation to that used for small value capacitors. If they were really 220uH they would have the value 221.

Answer (score 1):

[Panasonic SM inductors](http://industrial.panasonic.com/www-data/pdf/AGL0000/AGL0000CE6.pdf) use R in the part marking (for example, 2R6 corresponds to the 2.6 microhenry part on the specified datasheet).